# Binary classifier gone wrong. Predicting 1 always

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, classification, data-science

Below is me binary classifier in tensorflow. It is always predicting 1 and hence reporting 100 percent accuracy. Can someone explain where did I go wrong?

```
def mlp(curr_data_batch, y1, i, ep):
    with tf.variable_scope("name"+str(i), reuse=True):             
        b = tf.get_variable("bias")
        W = tf.get_variable("weights")
        y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x,W) + b)
        cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y), 
        reduction_indices=[1]))
        train_op = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate
        ).minimize(cross_entropy)       
        sess.run([train_op, y], feed_dict={x: curr_data_batch, y_: y1})
        correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
        accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
        print i, ep, ("Accuracy:", accuracy.eval({x: curr_data_batch, y_: 
        y1}, session=sess))
```

EDIT: I just saw weights are not getting updated. Is it happening due to variable scope?

Comment: I think that loss function is defined wrong. http://ml-cheatsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/loss_functions.html
Try using tensorflow's built in cross entropy loss (you don't need to apply softmax): tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits

Comment: Where are `x` and `y_` declared? They are placeholders?